# 0.315187 ACPI Error on Ubuntu 22.04 Lts

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi

Im new to ubuntu and got a laptop from my school
I have to do my exams on it and the day i wanted to finish them this came up i tried ACPI=off via recovery menu and it does not help

I put ubuntu 22.04 on a external harddrive with balenaetcher but i don’t know if it helps and how to do it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details.